# Web App worked last week, works fine on Ipad and Android, but now clogs on Iphone? NOTHING changed but SSL layer for push

Tags: ios

I just launched an IPHONE app...approved to apple store.

(marion IL official app) if you want to try

and it works fine on my ipad. Client says their iphone takes forever to load, and doesn't run right.

last week's version worked fine. Funny thing is I changed NO CODE (it's a web app with push notification) all I did is re-compress the IPA with the SSL Layer certificate for push.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue before. Two possibilities come to my mind:

- There is some memory pile up (you are storing something in an array/object), which is not being cleared time and again. For e.g. if you are getting something via GPS, but not clearing it over time. You'd only notice over time, as it takes a while to build up the data.

-The hosting company (GoDaddy in my case), enabled mobile websites, which were redirecting all calls from mobile device to a mobile site. This may not be in you case as you said it's working well on your ipad.

Comment: The array/object part I'm waay too  newbie to know what that means.  The app is a web app made with apppresser.